# How to add svg to an unordererd list?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to create a list dynamically that looks like a map legend.
So there should be a colored rectangle and a text besides the rectangle.  I want to organize the legend as an unordered list.
However, I am unable to get the svg to show.
I can see the element in the Inspector.
Here is my code:

```
let grp = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
let ul = document.createElement('ul');
grp.forEach(g => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');

  let spanSvg = document.createElement('span');
  let svg = document.createElement('svg');
  svg.class = 'svg-legend';
  svg.setAttribute('height', '20');
  svg.setAttribute('width', '40');
  svg.innerHTML = '<rect height="10" width="30" style="fill: rgb(17, 95, 103);"/>';
  spanSvg.appendChild(svg);

  let spanTxt = document.createElement('span');
  let txt = document.createTextNode(g);
  spanTxt.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(spanSvg);
  li.appendChild(spanTxt);
  ul.appendChild(li);

  document.getElementById('div').appendChild(ul);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.createElementNS`,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS

the namespace for svg is

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
```